# How to invoke contains directly on class rather than collection

Tags: java, contains

I would like to know how to be able to invoke the `contains` method directly on my class instead on its ArrayList variable. Best way to explain is really with the code below.

Thanks for your help.

```
public class Chord {
    ArrayList<Note> notes;
    // some more stuff not here
}

cmaj = new Chord("Cmaj");
cnote = new Note("C");

// what I have
cmaj.getNotes().contains(cnote);

// what I would like, is this possible, how?
cmaj.contains(cnote);
```

Comment: As a completely separate topic, it may make more sense to have `Note` be an [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) rather than a class (assuming that there's only 13 possible notes).

Comment: for the project at hand it makes sense to be a class, since there are many more methods associated. this was just a very short snippet. thanks for the suggestion though

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well you can just write the method yourself:

```
public class Chord {
    private final List<Note> notes;

    ...

    public boolean contains(Note note) {
        return notes.contains(note);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This is typical example of proxy methods ([see proxy patter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern)).

```
public class Chord {
    private final List<Note> notes = new ArrayList();

    public boolean contains(Note note) {
      return notes.contains(note);
    }

}
```

When you are using this type of methods, you should double check that reference is set before the object is delivered to client. If you do not pay attention you will get NullPointerException. And Try to stay consistent, if you decide to use contains in that way, `add`, `remove` and `reset` should also be implemented. And then the getter is no more required.

Answer (score 4):

Write a method contains() inside chord that simply delegates the call the the arraylist as below:

```
public class Chord {
    ArrayList<Note> notes;

    public boolean contains(Object o) {
       return notes.contains(o);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a method `contains` encapsulating the arrayList´s contains:

```
public class Chord {
    ArrayList<Note> notes;
    // some more stuff not here

    public boolean contains(Note note){
        return notes.contains(note);
    }
}
```